# Google Sheets API: Values pushed to sheet are percents

Tags: python, api, google-sheets-api

I'm writing a python script to update a google sheet. I first had written it so that it updates each sheet's values individually. Obviously, it's more efficient to write so that it batch updates, but in doing that, all the values that are pushed through become percents. For example, 1 becomes 100%, 53.2 becomes 5320% and so on.

**Sample code**

Here is the code I'm using to apply the batch update. Treat `rangelist` as a list object that contains the A1 range for the cell to be written to, and `valueslist` to be a list object that contains the values to be written to those ranges. There are no malfunctions with `rangelist`.

```
data = []
for i in xrange(len(rangelist)):
    data.append({'range': rangelist[i], values': valueslist[i]
body = {'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED', 'data': data}
response = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ID, body = body)
```

Things I have tried:

- Switching valueInputOption to RAW
- Casting each value in `valueslist` as a string with '=' at the beginning

Comment: Do you mean to say this only happens when you use batchUpdate but not spreadsheets.values.update?

Comment: Yes. And only when I send the values as ints/floats. For some reason, casting them as strings fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, casting the values to strings before putting them in the batch lists fixes this problem.